# Cannot get onMessage to show when App is in foreground

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am writing an app where you can press a button and it will send a 'Help' notification to every over app (this will be a closed group of around 100) I need the notifiction to pop up whatever state the app is in, I have the onResume and onLaunch sorted, but I cannot get it to display the notification when the app is in the foreground. There are many screens, I need the notification to show up on whatever screen the user is on.

I have tried many tutorials, but just cannot get it to work. I have the code in my initState on my Main page.

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =                    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  @override
  void initState() {
super.initState();

var initializationSettingsAndroid =
new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          AlertDialog(
            content: ListTile(
              title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
              subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Ok'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    );
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          AlertDialog(
            content: ListTile(
              title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
              subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Ok'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    );
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>
          AlertDialog(
            content: ListTile(
              title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
              subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Ok'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    );
  },
);
Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
if (payload != null) {
  debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High,ticker:'ticker');
  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'item x');
}
  }
    //  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Benidorm or Bust',
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
  ),
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => MyHomePage(),
    '/setup': (context) => Setup(),
    '/dayinit': (context) => Dayinit(),
    '/day1': (context) => Day1(),
    '/day2': (context) => Day2(),
    '/day3': (context) => Day3(),
    '/day4': (context) => Day4(),
    '/day5': (context) => Day5(),
    '/CheckList': (context) => CheckList(),
    '/eveinit': (context) => Eveinit(),
    'eve1eve': (context) => Eve1Eve(),

    // 'push':(context)=> Push(),
  },
);
  }

}
```

I am not getting any error, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, just move Firebase related code from "app" MyApp to MyHomePage widget. Inside MyHomePage it will have proper context. 
I've used this as an example https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart#L240